# Migrating from ag-grid-community to ag-grid-enterprise with Angular

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am already successfully using ag-grid-community in development. Now I wish to move to ag-grid-enterprise. I have my license. I following the rather ambiguous instructions in the Ag-Grid docs. But the docs don't work.

Docs say that I should be initialing a property [modules] of the enterprise grid. But there is no such property! And I do not know if I should remove the community version package in the vaguely-described installation process. Has anyone been through this migration?

Comment: Do you have code? Are you getting an error? Have you contacted their product support?

Comment: I got caught in ag-Grid's transition period to release 22.0.0. See my later comment below. I am now up and running on enterprise perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

No, you should not remove the community packages. The enterprise library is in addition to the community libraries, not instead of them.

AFAIK, all you should need to do is:

- install the ag-grid-enterprise package (npm install)
- add your license in main.ts, e.g.

  ```
  import {LicenseManager} from 'ag-grid-enterprise';

  LicenseManager.setLicenseKey(
    'your-license-key'
  );
  ```
- In any module where you want to use the grid, import the required ag-grid modules, e.g.

  ```
  import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
  import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
  import { AgGridModule } from 'ag-grid-angular';

  @NgModule({
    'imports': [
      CommonModule,
      AgGridModule.withComponents([])
    ]
  })
  export class MyModule {
  }
  ```

Comment: As of Monday morning, November 11, 2019, the module structure has been significantly changed with the release of 22.0.0 . You no longer need the community modules. The enterprise package now contains them all except for the framework modules. See https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-modules/ .